# Does Spring implement Graal specific APIs like ImageSingletons, Feature etc?

Tags: java, spring, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

When I search through Spring's entire repository, there are pretty much no references to [`ImageSingletons`](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/nativeimage/ImageSingletons.html), [`Feature`](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/nativeimage/hosted/Feature.html) (save for 1),
[`@AutomaticFeature`](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/com/oracle/svm/core/annotate/AutomaticFeature.html), or anything else I'd expect to see from something targeting GraalVM.

Can I still add `Feature`s myself? Can I expect Graal's APIs like `ImageSingletons` to work?

Comment: A quick search resulted in, for example [this file (`github.com`)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/HEAD/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/aot/nativex/feature/PreComputeFieldFeature.java#L23) that uses `org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.Feature`.

Comment: Some convo happening in https://twitter.com/kaqqao/status/1734598071437123619